# How to multiply a multi-layer raster (457 bands) with a one-layer raster (values of 0 and 1 ) in R with terra package?

Tags: r, stack, raster, terra

I want to multiply two rasters in R with 'terra'. **Raster1 has 457 bands** with EVI values meanwhile **raster2 is a one-layer raster** -of almost same extent- with **binary values (0 or 1)**. The result that I want to achieve is to get **raster1** (with the 457 original bands) **with values only in pixels that has a value = 1 in raster2**. That's why I want to multiply them.

I have tried:

`result <- raster1 * raster2`

`result <- overlay(raster1, raster2, fun = function(x,y){return(x*y)}, unstack=FALSE)`

But it doesn't work. I appreciate some help.

Comment: "it does not work" is not a very good description of your problem

Answer (score 1):

Example data (please always include some):

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/logo.tif", package="terra")
r1 <- rast(c(f, f))
r2 <- rast(r1, nlyr=1)
set.seed(0)
values(r2) <- sample(c(0,1), ncell(r2), replace=TRUE)
```

Solution

```
x <- mask(r1, r2, maskvalue=0)
```

If you multiply (`r1 * r2`), all values that are zero in `r2` become zero in the output, but you want them to become `NA`, and that is what `mask` will do for you.

Alternatively, you could first change the cells that are `0` to `NA`, and then multiply, but that is unnecessarily convoluted:

```
m <- subst(r2, 0, NA)
y <- r1 * m
```